# Add column2 before column1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have table structure with 3 colums (column1, column2, column3) and i want to put another column with  sql statement like:

```
alter table tbl_name add column4
```

but i need to put it between column1 and column2

may i do something like in MYSQL:

```
alter table tbl_name add column4 after column1
```

Comment: You can open the table in SQL Mgmt studio and change the sequence of the columns, but basically what SQL Server does in the background is create a new table with the desired columns, move the data from the old to the new table, and drop the old table.

Comment: i see that i have no alternative choice for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SQL Server allows you to do anything like that.  If you want to put a column  in the middle, you'll need to create a new table with the desired layout, migrate the data, delete the old table, and rename the new table.

Comment: strange that ms sql does not support this simple think :(

Comment: SQL tables should really not depend or rely on the sequence of the fields, it's really not something that should matter in the world of relational tuples.

Answer (score 1):

@bdukes is correct.  This is essentially what SSMS does when you add a column in any place other than the last position of the table.  You could, however, achieve something similar using views.  That is, simply add your column to the end of the table, then create a view which has the columns in a different order.  Use the view instead of the actual table.  I only offer this as one alternative that can be useful in certain situations.  I'm not necessarily recommending it for your situation.  Generally, I use the designer in SSMS and haven't had any problems with it updating tables when inserting a column.  Backups, of course, are your friend!

Answer (score 1):

A more fundamental question is why you want to do this?  Other than the default display of columns in the SQL Enterprise manager, the order of columns is irrelevant.  You can order the columns output by a SQL query any way you want, no matter how the columns are 'natively' ordered inside the database.

In fact, from an academic perspective, one of the cardinal properties of a RDBMS 'Relation' (the academic name for a table), is that the 'attributes' (columns) of a relation are unordered.

This is not to say that wanting the 'default' order to be a certain way is not reason enough... I often drop and recreate tables for exactly that reason... But just understand that the order doesn't mater for anything else.

Comment: i have tbl_lang table with word ields like lang_Submit, lang_Send and alerts like alert_Forgot_Your_Password, alert_Incorrect_Password. with foreach in my app i build html form but i need that first will be fields with prefix lang_ and then alert_. now i have issue that i need to add new word with prefix lang_. i cant do it with MSMS cuz i have multiple DBs its mean that i have run sql that adds field for all DBs

Comment: Then simply add it at the end, but in your code, write SQL to generate output set that outputs the fields in the order that you want

Answer (score 1):

in sql server 2005 you can save a change script of table changes, so for instance i created a test table, with col1, col2 and col3. Then added col4 between col1 and col2. I saved the change scripts and this is what it generated.

Have a look

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_zzzzzzzz
    (
    col1 nchar(10) NULL,
    col4 nchar(10) NULL,
    col2 nchar(10) NULL,
    col3 nchar(10) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.zzzzzzzz)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_zzzzzzzz (col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.zzzzzzzz WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.zzzzzzzz
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_zzzzzzzz', N'zzzzzzzz', 'OBJECT' 
GO
COMMIT
```

seems like there is no way to simply add the column. Also, be aware of the transaction, this will drop the original table, so it is good to use a transaction

Comment: ok, i see that u did same think like MSMS does. i afraid about identity ids with temp table. i must create temp table without primary key with int type and then create like auto numeric :)